Default 'noindex' Robots Meta Tag in Next.js App – How to remove it?

"I have created first time app in next js also with the server side rendering. I added a meta tag with robots: index, but when I inspect the page source, another meta tag with robots: noindex is automatically injected, which prevents search engines from indexing the page. How to fixed it "
